# about php full calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

When I click on an item in the calendar it will show its particular task. After one second the calendar will disappear. But I want to show the task without disappearing. When I add a function to call the calendar according to the item,  then this problem has started.

This is the code into the jquery

```
{
    guyid = "";

    $('.guyid').click(function (){
        this.guyid = $(this).attr('id');
    //  alert('test:'+this.guyid);
            CalenderCall(this.guyid);

    });

    function CalenderCall(guyid){

//alert(guyid);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                events: [
                    {
                        title: guyid,
                        start: '2016-02-04'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Event1',
                        start: '2016-02-04'
                    },

                    {
                        title: 'Event1',
                        start: '2016-02-17'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: '2016-02-06',
                        end: '2016-02-10'
                    }

                    // etc...
                    ],
                    color: 'yellow',   // an option!
                    textColor: 'black' // an option!
        });
    }

});
```

this is the body part

```
<!-- <div style="width: auto; height: 200px; border: 2px solid black;"></div> -->
<a href="tasks.php"><b>Tasks</b></a><br>
<div style="position: absolute;">
<?php
    $phplink = mysql_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '');
    if (!$phplink) {
        die("Could not connect:" .mysql_error());
    }
    $db = mysql_select_db('jhoro_pm', $phplink) or die("Could not connect to db:" .mysql_error());
    $result_guy = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, can_login FROM person WHERE can_login=1");
    while ($row_guy=mysql_fetch_array($result_guy)) {
        //echo '<input type="hidden" class="guyid" value="' .$row_guy[0]. '" />';
        echo '<a href="index.php" class="guyid" id="' .$row_guy[0]. '">' .$row_guy[1]. '</a><br>';
    }
?>
```

this is the item without the calendar. When click anyone of them the task will show with the calendar. but after one second calendar disappears

[image]

Comment: I think you want to show calendar with tasks of selected person, right?

Comment: exactly  Chintan Mirani

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then you have to do something like below

First of all change your code with below one.

```
<!-- <div style="width: auto; height: 200px; border: 2px solid black;"></div> -->
<a href="tasks.php"><b>Tasks</b></a><br>
<div style="position: absolute;">
<?php
    $phplink = mysql_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '');
    if (!$phplink) {
        die("Could not connect:" .mysql_error());
    }
    $db = mysql_select_db('jhoro_pm', $phplink) or die("Could not connect to db:" .mysql_error());
    $result_guy = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, can_login FROM person WHERE can_login=1");
    while ($row_guy=mysql_fetch_array($result_guy)) {
        echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="guyid" id="' .$row_guy[0]. '">' .$row_guy[1]. '</a><br>';

    }

        echo '<input type="hidden" id="selectedPerson" class="guyid" value="' .$row_guy[0]. '" />';
?>
```

1. Remove   href="index.php"  from your anchor tag. (href will call every click, that's why your calendar disappears.
2. Set hidden field for selected person. (Out side while loop).

Now, some fine tuning of your jQuery code.

```
{
    guyid = "";

    $('.guyid').click(function (){
        this.guyid = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#selectedPerson').val(this.guyid);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                events: [
                    {

                        title: 1,
                        start: '2016-02-04'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 2,
                        start: '2016-02-04'
                    },

                    {
                        title: 3,
                        start: '2016-02-17'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 4,
                        start: '2016-02-06',
                        end: '2016-02-10'
                    }

                    ],
                    eventRender: function(event, element) {
                       return (($('#selectedPerson').val()) == event.title);
                   },
                    color: 'yellow',   // an option!
                    textColor: 'black' // an option!
        });
});
```

This will work surely.
If you still stuck anywhere, add comment.

Comment: it's not working Chintan Mirani. Now the task isn't come according to the person though calendar is showing now.... :(

Comment: your guyid and event.title must match.
On .guyid click guyid must set to hidden field.
are these criteria working as mentioned?

Comment: Chintan Mirani, to show the task according to the person may be add an array into the events is a better idea....we use here manual event.....what do you say ?

Comment: yes, these are static demo events. You have to replace with your server actual data. Due to static demo events your guyid and title are mismatched.

Comment: Only show the task for the first 3 people of the list after using your code.... may be array would be the solution

Comment: but for the array passing we need a function

Comment: There is one another solution is that you have to make ajax call on every person selection and set json response to events. Do you know this?

Comment: ya i know little bit about those ajax and json....and i think for that i have to make another file for json...and return response from that...but it will be better for me if you explain it to me...

Comment: Adding one more solution. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your existing code (that you mention in your question) as it is.

Just add simple ajax url as below to load person wise task.

```
events: "urltofetchpersonwisetasks/?guyid="+guyid,
```

And server get this request with guyid as request parameter and make database call to get person's task and send json response.  Like json_encode(person_task_array). This will automatically load selected person;s task.

Comment: it's not working Chintan Mirani. okay thanks for your trying...:)